# How to show text beneath the rotating image

Tags: html, css

I want to show some text below the loading image.But text is aligned to different position in different browser. I have attached the screen shot of chrome and IE browser

Below is the HTML i have used

```css
.LoaderwithText {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.loader {
  border: 12px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 12px solid #3498db;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  -ms-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
}

#LoaderText {
  Color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}


@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="LoaderwithText">
  <a class="loader"></a>
  <p id="LoaderText">Deleting...</p>
</div>
```

What i am missing in the style that should make it work in all browser.

[IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcc9r.png)

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcc9r.png)

Comment: **I have attached the screen shot of chrome and IE browser** -- I guess you forgot to add these in?

Comment: Please wait... Imgur is down... :( Can't see any pics now. Anyone else facing the issue?

Comment: I have added the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `flex`, you need to size the container to center its content:

`Absolute` element can also be centered via coordonates and `margin` if they have a static size.

```css
.LoaderwithText {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* update*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.loader {
  border: 12px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 12px solid #3498db;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  -ms-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  /* update*/
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}

#LoaderText {
  Color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}


@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="LoaderwithText">
  <a class="loader"></a>
  <p id="LoaderText">Deleting...</p>
</div>
```